# SimpleCursorAdapter LoaderManager

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I'm using API 15 and SimpleCursorAdapter does no longer work and I am suppose to use LoadManager, but when I look at the the example on Androids developer website the example starts with: SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter; since SimpleCursorAdapter is deprecated how can I use LoadManager. I have been unable to find any examples. 
The only other way to get my sqllite data into a listview is create an adapter and load the data into a list record by record then use setAdapter. 
If any one know of any example using LoadManager I will appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: why ? whats the problem with SimpleCursorAdapter ?? its works fine with sqlite at all

Comment: just a constructor is deprecated in api 15 . so you can still use SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: I agree `SimpleCursorAdapter` is deprecated so folks should move to `LoaderManager`.  Just learning this myself so I don't feel confident in posting a solution but I found this link which is probably helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html